# Do You Need The Gradle Sonar Plugin To Run SonarQube From Bamboo?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, bamboo

I have a Java Gradle project and I am trying to run SonarQube from Bamboo.

The SonarQube Bamboo plugin has a "Sonar Gradle" task.

I can't work out from the documentation if this task runs Sonar itself or if it expects me to have the sonar plugin in my build.gradle.

At the moment I don't have any reference to sonar in my build.gradle.

When I run it in Bamboo it fails with "Task 'sonarqube' not found in root project"

That implies that it is expecting me to modify my build.gradle. However, maven colleagues who are running it successfully are saying that they didn't have to modify their pom.

If I do have to put everything in my build.gradle what is the point of this Bamboo task when I could just run it directly using a gradle runner?

What is the correct way to use this Sonar Gradle task in Bamboo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to this integration: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212756/sonar-for-bamboo

> I can't work out from the documentation if this task runs Sonar itself or if it expects me to have the sonar plugin in my build.gradle.

It expects you to apply the Gradle plugin to the project and configure the plugin as well. Per the docs [here](https://mibexsoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SONARBAMBOO/pages/5537953/Gradle):

> Installation and configuration of the Gradle SonarQube plug-in is described in the [Sonar Wiki](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle?src=sidebar).

And the linked wiki is also directions for applying/configuring the Gradle plugin.

> maven colleagues who are running it successfully are saying that they didn't have to modify their pom.

It's possible that either:

1. They have already applied the plugin to their project
2. There is a global SonarQube Maven configuration as described in [Global Settings](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven#header-2)

> If I do have to put everything in my build.gradle what is the point of this Bamboo task when I could just run it directly using a gradle runner?

The point of it is so you do not have to write out the task yourself and whatever else the task does for you. You can certainly write your own task or use a provided one.

> What is the correct way to use this Sonar Gradle task in Bamboo?

There is no correct way, it's whatever works for your projects workflow.

Comment: So I just apply the plugin but don't add any tasks or anything else?

Comment: The SonarQube plugin adds a task as you can see [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarqube/gradle/SonarQubePlugin.java#L78) and does other stuff as well. Applying the plugin should be sufficient enough according to the Bamboo docs.